# Heroku failed to push some refs to "...."

Tags: django, git, heroku, django-oscar

I got this error when I did git push heroku master. I know I have to change some info about django_oscar in requirements.txt. But don't know what to change to. Please help

```
       Obtaining django-oscar from git+git@github.com:tangentlabs/django-oscar.git@482d83208a5ec716873f9951f96
81d428cc452fa#egg=django_oscar-dev (from -r requirements.txt (line 33))
         Cloning git@github.com:tangentlabs/django-oscar.git (to 482d83208a5ec716873f9951f9681d428cc452fa) to
./.heroku/src/django-oscar
Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
         Complete output from command /usr/bin/git clone -q git@github.com:tangentlabs/django-oscar.git /app/.
heroku/src/django-oscar:

       ----------------------------------------
       Command /usr/bin/git clone -q git@github.com:tangentlabs/django-oscar.git /app/.heroku/src/django-oscar
 failed with error code 128 in None
       Storing complete log in /app/.pip/pip.log

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
```

The only pip.log file I found in my pc

```
------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip-script.py run on 06/25/13 10:02:36
Downloading/unpacking SomePackage

  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/SomePackage/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/SomePackage/: HTTP Error 404: Not Found (SomePackage does not have any releases)
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/SomePackage/ when looking for download links for SomePackage
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  URLs to search for versions for SomePackage:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/SomePackage/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/SomePackage/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/SomePackage/: HTTP Error 404: Not Found (SomePackage does not have any releases)
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/SomePackage/ when looking for download links for SomePackage
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement SomePackage

No distributions at all found for SomePackage

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\pip\basecommand.py", line 139, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\pip\commands\install.py", line 266, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 1026, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\pip\index.py", line 171, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for SomePackage
```

Comment: what does `/app/.pip/pip.log` say ?

Comment: @karthikr I can't find pip.log

Comment: @karthikr I have updated the question with the only pip.log file I found

Comment: You have a package called `SomePackage`, which is specified to be installed in `C:\Python27\Scripts\pip-script.py`.

Comment: @karthikr I didn't get what you are trying to say..

Comment: `Downloading/unpacking SomePackage` does not seem right to me.. SomePackage is not a valid python library

Comment: @karthikr ok but I haven't written SomePackage anywhere in my code and requirements.txt file. I think it has something to do with this `git+git@github.com:tangentlabs/django-oscar.git@482d83208a5ec716873f9951f96
81d428cc452fa#egg=django_oscar-dev` It can't clone from the above address which needs to be change but I don't know what to change in it